# Match taking into account characters like ä ë ï ö ü, á, é, í, ó, ú

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

Hey I am running against a small problem that I do not know the answer of.

I have 2 lists:
List 1 has all my data, for example

```
Märio
Toad
Bowser
Pëach
Luigi
```

List 2 has data too (but this list doesnt have the ä's and ë's:

```
Mario
Luigi
Toad
Peach
Daisy
```

**My question is, can I match these 2 lists regardless of if they have ä's and ë's?**

Per cel in list 2, I want to scroll through the entire list 1 to check if it is there, regardless of ä's and ë's?
So it would look something like this:

```
Märio   Mario  TRUE
Toad    Luigi  TRUE
Bowser  Toad   TRUE
Pëach   Peach  TRUE
Luigi   Daisy  FALSE
```

So what I have been trying is using Select, but that doesnt work because it searches exactly for the word and also judges this based on  ä's and ë's.
Any idea how I can do this?

(also sorry for my english)

**Update**, using the formula from doubleunary it works only one way.
With that I mean that when you put a name with a character like ä or ö in the second list, then you compare it with a name that is in the fist list without an ä or ö, it gives back a false. For example:

```
Märio   Mario  TRUE
Peach   Pëach  FALSE
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regexreplace()` to deburr those text strings, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  not(iserror( 
    match( 
      lower(B2:B6), 
      regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(
        lower(A2:A6), 
        "ä|á|à|â", "a"), 
        "ë|é|è|ê", "e"), 
        "ï|í|ì|î", "i"), 
        "ö|ó|ò|ô", "o"), 
        "ü|ú|ù|û", "u"), 
      0 
    )
  ) ) 
)
```

To deburr both the search keys and the text to search, apply `regexreplace()` to both:

```
=arrayformula( 
  lambda( 
    searchFor, textToSearch, 
    lambda( 
      searchForDeburr, textToSearchDeburr, 
      not(iserror(match(searchForDeburr, textToSearchDeburr, 0))) 
    )( 
      regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(
        lower(searchFor), 
        "ä|á|à|â", "a"), 
        "ë|é|è|ê", "e"), 
        "ï|í|ì|î", "i"), 
        "ö|ó|ò|ô", "o"), 
        "ü|ú|ù|û", "u"), 
      regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(
        lower(textToSearch), 
        "ä|á|à|â", "a"), 
        "ë|é|è|ê", "e"), 
        "ï|í|ì|î", "i"), 
        "ö|ó|ò|ô", "o"), 
        "ü|ú|ù|û", "u") 
    ) 
  )( 
    B2:B, A2:A6 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: this works great!

Comment: But one thing I noticed, is that it doesnt work the other way around. With that I mean that when you put a name with a character like ä or ö in the second list, then you compare it with a name that is in the fist list without an ä or ö, it gives back a false.

Comment: I have made an example in the original post

Comment: Edited the answer to add another solution per your new requirements.

Comment: Hey doubleynaru, thank you for answering my question and linking to that document! Indeed! I have accepted your proposal as a answer, thanks for linking that document! Thanks again!